# Parameters for find function

Tags: python, find, beautifulsoup

I'm using beautiful soup (in Python). I have such hidden input object:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_build_id" id="form-531f740522f8c290ead9b88f3da026d2" value="form-531f740522f8c290ead9b88f3da026d2"  />
```

I need in id/value.

Here is my code:

```
mainPageData = cookieOpener.open('http://page.com').read()
soupHandler = BeautifulSoup(mainPageData)

areaId = soupHandler.find('input', name='form_build_id', type='hidden')

TypeError: find() got multiple values for keyword argument 'name'
```

I tried to change code:

```
print soupHandler.find(name='form_build_id', type='hidden')
None
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try using the [alternative `attrs` keyword](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#arg-attrs):

```
areaId = soupHandler.find('input', attrs={'name':'form_build_id', 'type':'hidden'})
```

> You can't use a keyword argument
>   called name because the Beautiful Soup
>   search methods already define a name
>   argument. You also can't use a Python
>   reserved word like for as a keyword
>   argument.
>
> Beautiful Soup provides a special
>   argument called attrs which you can
>   use in these situations. attrs is a
>   dictionary that acts just like the
>   keyword arguments.